# Cent OS + VSFTP, 553 could not create file, how to allow uploading of files?

Tags: centos, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have a ftp server running on Cent OS VM. 
the goal:

- public map can be seen by everyone (readonly for anonymous users, write for logged in users)
- upload map can only be seen by local users logged in and they can
  upload files (= write permission)

I can't create files with Filezilla (also not in the public folder) if I log in with a local user account of ftp server

I also set this bool value:

```
setsebool ftp_home_dir on
```

my vsftpd config:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/srv/shares/public
local_root=/srv/shares
no_anon_password=YES

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022
```

I get an 553 could not create file

Are there any setsebool values that I forgot to set?

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect SELinux as the culprit (ie, if any violations show up in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` when you attempt the upload or if the upload completes successfully after setting SELinux to permissive mode), then look into [audit2allow](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01) to turn your failure audit messages into SELinux rules that will allow the actions you're attempting to perform.